# Find the laurent series for $e^{2/(z-1)}$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I'm starting to learn about Laurent series. The way I understand it is that it is the same as a Taylor expansion, but with negative terms in addition to the positive terms.

I may be wrong, but isn't the general goal to get it into the form $\frac{1}{1-z}$? And then from there the expansion is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$ and $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}$

---

I found some other notes online that kind of point in a current direction as to how to go about solving this problem. Below is my attempt.

We know that $$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

So if we change $z$ to $\frac{2}{z-1}$, we get

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\frac{2}{z-1})^n}{n!}$$

Comment: There is no one Laurent series. Laurent series, like Taylor series, always comes with a point for which they are expanded about. The result you have found is the Laurent series about $z=1$. Is this what you are after or do you want the Laurent series about $z=0$?

Comment: @Winther the problem doesn't specify. It just says what I wrote in the title

Comment: I guess that it's likely that you are to find the series expanded about  $z=1$ then  (as you have done) as the series about $z=0$ will just coincide with the Taylor series of the function about $z=0$ (since the function is analytical at $z=0$).

Comment: @Winther so what I understand is that for Laurent series we only expand at a point where there is a singularity?

Comment: Yes. That is the interesting points to expand about as the series will tell you about the nature of the singularity at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor series of $$e^x=\sum\limits_{k=o}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Set $x=2/(z-1)$

$$e^{2/(z-1)}=\sum\limits_{k=o}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{2}{z-1}\right)^k}{k!}$$

The goal when you want laurent series is to get this form: $\sum C_n z^{-n}$ the power should be negative.

Comment: If it actually was as simple as swapping for the new value for $x$, then I don't understand the whole point of Laurent series.

Comment: It is a power series which includes terms of negative degree

Comment: Looking at your answer, if I started writing the terms starting at $k=0$ to infinity, where would the first negative term come from? I guess it would depend on the value of $z$, no?

Comment: the first negative terms will start at $k=1,2,\dots$, no it's not depend on the value of $z$

Comment: If $k=1$, then the term is $\frac{\frac{2}{z-1}}{1!}$, if $k=2$ the term is $\frac{(\frac{2}{z-1})^2}{2!}$. Where is the negative sign?

Comment: Yes, there is $\frac{2^2(z-1)^{-2}}{2!}$

Comment: I made a mistake in my last comment but I can't edit anymore. Yes, the $z$ term is being raised to the negative power, but then how does that make the *whole term* negative?

Comment: The whole term should not be negative necessarily it could be positive